# A donde, en donde, donde?

Tags: gramática

Como se traduciría la siguiente frase:

> "now I’m where I belong"

- Ahora estoy donde pertenezco?
- Ahora estoy en donde pertenezco?
- Ahora estoy a donde pertenezco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Donde* y *en donde* son [igualmente válidos](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=qMMxvDB32D697zToZQ) en una expresión como ésta, en la que se indica un lugar donde algo o alguien se encuentra (estático). Generalmente se dice *estar donde* porque es más corto, pero *estar en donde* también es correcto.

No se dice *a donde* (que también se escribe *adonde*) porque la preposición *a* indica movimiento hacia un lugar, y éste no es el caso (*adonde* se usa, por ejemplo, con *ir*, en frases como *Vamos adonde quieras*).

*Pertenecer* no corresponde a esta acepción del verbo inglés *belong*. Usarlo de esta manera es un anglicismo, que es común ver en las traducciones de películas, por ejemplo, pero que no es correcto en español. "Now I’m where I belong" debería traducirse

> *Ahora estoy donde debo estar.*

o quizá

> *Ahora estoy donde me corresponde estar.*

o bien

> *Ahora estoy en el lugar donde debo estar.*